# Can Netbeans(MinGW compiler for c/c++) call on arbitrary C/C++ DLLs(compiled in VS'05)?

Tags: java, c++, visual-c++, java-native-interface

AS above, i encountered a "undefined reference error ***imp*_ZN12classNameC1Ev**" when using JNI to call upon class functions in arbitrary provided DLL. I am wondering if name mangling incompatibilty for the 2 different compilers is the source of error?

To be exact, can a code compiled by MinGW(gcc/g++) call another code's class function compiled by visualStudio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compiling is not exactly the problem. The problem is at **linking**. If you have C++ interfaces then name mangling will definitively make you trouble. Each compiler has its own name mangling scheme. Too bad, they should have standardized maybe this too in the C++ standard...

One way to workaround the problem is to create a small C wrapper API around the C++ Dll you have (which must be compiled with MSVC) and use this C API from Netbeans. (Eventually making some C++ header-only wrapper for the classes in the c++ dll to make it appear like the original Api. That's two level of wrapping but I have no idea if this can be solved in an easier way.